# Writting to a Tun/Tap interface

Tags: network-interface, devices, file-descriptors, tap

Recently I've been using a `tun` interface to redirect the Internet traffic through my methods. To do so, I followed [this](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) tutorial.

My idea is to have a program which receives the IP packets that go to `10.0.0.15` through `tun0` interface and redirect them to `customSend()`, which sends the packet to another computer (using another protocol, but this is not relevant). The other computer would respond to that packet and `customRecv()` would get it and send it the `tun0` interface.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
void customSend() {
    // whenever a packet is sent from my computer to 10.0.0.15 the
    // read method will be triggered.
    size = read(tunfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    // send packet using another protocol
    write(otherProtocolSendfd, buffer, size);
}

void customRecv() {
    // whenever a packet is received from another protocol
    // this will be triggered
    size = read(otherProtocolRecvfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    // redirect the packet to tun0
    write(tunfd, buffer, size);
}

void main() {
    // init the tun0 interface
    int tunfd = init_tun_interface();
    // create a thread running customSend and one running customRecv
}
```

To make it easier to understand, I'll show an example.

1. Workstation1 (`10.0.0.14`) pings Workstation2 (`10.0.0.15`)
2. ping application creates an ICMP packet and sends it through `tun0`.
3. `read` method at `customSend()` intercepts the ICMP packet.
4. `customSend()` thread sends it to the other protocol method through `otherProtocolSendfd`.
5. The other protocol sends the message through the network and the ping packet reaches Workstation2.
6. Workstation2 replies with a pong message.
7. The other protocol receives the network message and writes it through `otherProtocolRecvfd`
8. `read` mehod at `customRecv()` receives the response packet and the `write` method sends it to `tun0` interface.
9. `tun0` interface gives the response (pong) packet to the ping application.

For now, I have implemented the `customSend()` part, which does work and transmits the message to the other computer.

My concern is about the writting part. Will a `write` to `tunfd` actually send the message to the interface or will I receive it at the `customSend()` method, which is what I would expect. If it's the latter, how could I send the message to the interface?

Also, and this is a more general question, will I have any concurrency problems if I have a thread executing `customToSend()` and another one executing `customRecv()`, since both are using `tunfd`.

Thanks!

Comment: The usual way to do this is to use `select` on `tunfd` and `otherProtocolRecvfd`, and make sure that writes are non-blocking. Simpler than threads. I don't understand the question "will write to tunfd send the message, or will I receive it at customSend()?".

Comment: @dirkt What do you mean by `non-blocking` writes? As for the latter, I was wondering if `write(tunfd, buffer, size);` would trigger `read(tunfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));` or would actually transfer the packet to the ping application.

Comment: Writing to `tunfd` will send the packet out of the corresponding `tunX` interface. Any packet send to `tunX` by an application will eventually be read from `tunfd`. "Non-blocking" means the system call returns immediately and the data is buffered by the kernel. Depending on what exactly you do, maybe you can get away with blocking I/O as well.

Comment: @dirkt When you say `out of the corresponding tunX interface` you mean out to the application which is expecting the response, right? So in a case of a ping, writting the response packet to `tunfd` would cause the ping app to receive it.

Comment: I meant "just like an incoming packet from the LAN on `ethX` is processed by the kernel, writing to tunfd causes the kernel to process the packet just as if it was incoming from `tunX`". So yes, a ping application expecting a reply would receive this packet, or a ping application on another computer in the LAN would cause it to be forwarded into the LAN, or whatever the current routing etc. causes to happen".

Comment: Note that TCP does not respect message boundary so if you want to transmit your packets over TCP (or anything similar) you might want to add some framing information (like prepending the packet length to each message).